# Python selenium Chrome driver

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to use selenium and chromedriver. I have downloaded the latest chromedriver and I am trying this.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\Anaconda2\Scripts\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("google.com")
```

I get chrome to come up but I get the following:
[image]

Why does this not go to google.com?

Answer (score 0):

It is fine if that happens. Chrome, by default, tells you to disable developer mode on Chrome, to prevent viruses and whatnot. It is fine, just keep in mind that having developer mode on will make your computer vulnerable to viruses. If your code is not working, then that is a different question.

Comment: Possibly because you did not enter the full address, etc; `http://www.google.com`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

When you work with `Selenium` 3.4.0, `chromedriver` v2.30 and `Google Chrome` 59.0 through `Python 3.6.1`, you can use the argument `chrome_options` while initiating the `WebDriver` instance to disable the extensions and disable the infobar as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path="C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get('http://google.com/')
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.